# node.js get the mouse double click speed from the OS

Tags: node.js, operating-system

Is it possible to get the mouse double click speed value from the OS with node ?
I try to get it to apply it for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is not possible to get the time difference from the OS If you want only the time difference use some javascript logic to get the time difference my recommedation

```
 var lastClickTime = 0;
$("#testLink").click(function() {
    var d = new Date();

    lastClickTime= d.getTime();
    console.log("last time clicked " + lastClickTime );
});
```

store the values and do the functionality according to that 
hope it will help

Comment: I found a solution only for windows :/. I use the npm package windows-registry et and check the value of the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER.Control Panel.Mouse.DoubleClickSpeed

Comment: Thanks for your response !